# MEAN.JS: Slow charging time

Tags: angularjs, performance, bundle, minify, meanjs

### Situation

I'm using [**MEAN.JS**](http://meanjs.org/) framework ([MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/), [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/), [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/)).

I ***bundled*** and ***minified*** with `grunt build` all the AngularJS `.js` files (*Controllers, Factories, Services, Directives...*).

The result are 2 files:

```
css: 'public/dist/application.min.css',
js: 'public/dist/application.min.js'
```

### Problem

The file `application.min.js` is *266kb*. When a user load the web , this file takes **5 minutes** delay before the page is loaded . (Using [**AWS EC2**](http://aws.amazon.com/es/ec2/)).

```
GET /dist/application.min.js 200 274.939 ms - -
```

*274939 ms* **>** *274.939 s* **>** ***4.58 min***

The same problem was happening before the bundling and minified. I was thinking that the solution of this problem was the bundling and minified of all the AngularJS files. But isn't it.

After the `.js` files are loaded, the application is very fast, but takes 5min to loaded...

- **What I need to do to solve this problem?** My project is large and have a lot of files, and I understand that AngularJS is for projects like this...

Comment: This sounds like a serious bandwidth issue.

Comment: Not enough known for anyone here to help. Not even clear what those times refer to exactly

Comment: This problem occurs using AWS EC2. In localhost the loading is fast...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved the problem!**

Finally the problem isn't for the bundled and minified 266kb file!

The problem was about the `Liveload.js` file. In localhost, the  *Liveload library* is good for development, but not in the production mode that this file takes a lot of time for charging the page.

The solution is remove the Liveload dependence.